# Multicell in Array FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi sir  i need a help on how to make  the data inside the array to be in a textWrap using multicell

here is my code

```
        foreach($data as $row){ //CGANHE THIS ACCORDING TO HEADER

            $this->Cell($w[0],4,$row[0],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');

            $this->Cell($w[1],4,$row[1],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');

            $this->Cell($w[2],4,$row[2],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');

            $this->Cell($w[3],4,$row[3],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');

            $this->Cell($w[4],4,$row[4],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
            $this->SetFont('');

            $this->Ln();
            $fill =! $fill;
        }

      $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');


      $this->Ln(50);
      $this->Ln(50);

    }

}
```

Need Help Badly Tnx a lot 
This is really driving me insane, so if anyone has any ideas, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Is this all the code you have so far? If not, can you show what else you have that's relevant?

Comment: nnow i just updated the code how can i have make the multicell when i show the data 
|wordwrap|wordwrap |wordwrap| <-- how can i make it so that it will not destroy the colum line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every cell you want wrapped will have to be a MultiCell:

For example:

```
$this->MultiCell($w[0],4,$row[0],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
```

Text will be wrapped automatically if the right cell border is reached.

See also: [FPDF-documentation for MultiCell](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)

Comment: how can i use it on my array?
 $data[] = array($row['item_qty'],                     
                $row['itemname'],
                number_format($row['item_price'],2),
                number_format($row['total'],2),

             );

Comment: Please read the documentation, so you'll know what to do...
Your `foreach` statement should allow for every row to be printed already... Although I'd use the associative keys to reference to it within your `foreach`.